# Issue with Nb-select multiple control

Tags: angular, typescript

**Current behavior:**
I am using the nb-select multiple options to select multiple items and show them back after the screen loads. Unfortunately, I am not able to bind the selectedItems.

**Expected behavior:**
Since it is multiple options I am sending an array of selected options and it should show them on screen

**Steps to reproduce:**

**Related code:**

```
  <nb-card>
  <nb-card-header>Hello World</nb-card-header>
  <nb-card-body>
      <nb-select
        [(selected)]="selectedItems"
        multiple
        placeholder="Multiple Select"  >
        <nb-option *ngFor="let project of dropdownList" [value]="project.item_id">
          {{ project.item_text}}
        </nb-option>
      </nb-select>
    </nb-card-body>
  </nb-card>

dropdownList = [];
selectedItems = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.dropdownList = [
      { item_id: 1, item_text: 'A' },
      { item_id: 2, item_text: 'B' },
      { item_id: 3, item_text: 'C' },
      { item_id: 4, item_text: 'D' },
      { item_id: 5, item_text: 'E' }
    ];
    this.selectedItems = [
      { item_id: 3, item_text: 'C' },
      { item_id: 4, item_text: 'D' }
    ];
}
```

Here is the URL for sample code [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-wh14ma?file=src/app/home/home.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `item_id` in option `[value]="project.item_id"` and passing array of objects in `selectedItems` so you need define compare function using `item_id` like this [nbSelectComponent doc](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/select/examples#nbselectcomponent):

```
<nb-select
    [(selected)]="selectedItems"
    multiple
    [compareWith]="compareById"
    placeholder="Multiple Select"  >
    <nb-option *ngFor="let project of dropdownList" [value]="project.item_id">
      {{ project.item_text}}
    </nb-option>
  </nb-select>
```

and in your component.ts define the compare function:

```
compareById(v1, v2): boolean {
    return v1.item_id=== v2.item_id;
  }
```

and for some reason this approach didn't work on stackbliz maybe `compareWith` not supported in your nebular version.

so the workaround solution is to change the `selectedItems` to be like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dropdownList = [
      { item_id: 1, item_text: 'A' },
      { item_id: 2, item_text: 'B' },
      { item_id: 3, item_text: 'C' },
      { item_id: 4, item_text: 'D' },
      { item_id: 5, item_text: 'E' }
    ];
    this.selectedItems = [
      3,4
    ];
}
```